# I need a situation where people are angry at a person for getting a stroke

Tags: diseases

I need this situation for starting up a story:

Person A is loved by his surroundings and lives a generally good and healthy life. Person A gets a stroke and gets to the hospital, after 4 weeks, everything is fine. There are no lasting damages. Person A leaves the hospital and then, most of his surroundings are angry at him *because* he had a stroke.

Since nobody choses to get a stroke, especially not if one lives healthily, I personally cannot think of somebody who might be angry at someone for having a stroke (I *understand* that close people may be angry over time, when caring all the time delivers no results, but I need the situation to end *without lasting damages*). But still, can you think of situations where this scenario might occur? What must have happened before so that people could react that way reasonably?

Comment: This looks like you're asking for story help not help building a fictional world.

Comment: Some people can get angry at other for a most whimsical reason or no reason at all. Would that serve your purpose?

Comment: This really isn't a world-building question, but the best reason I can think of is if the timing of his stroke and coincidentally murky symptoms around it convinces everyone that he faked it. For example, if it happened right before a major business event, and he had made some jokes that make him look suspicious, etc. etc. Then his excellent health and full recovery could even be a mark against him.

Comment: Oops, didn't see the @AustinA answer. Upvoted.

Comment: @Brythan The question you proposed would be asking about our existing understanding of medicine so it's not a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 3):

What about if...

**Everybody thinks he faked the stroke.**

Perhaps an antagonist plots against him? This distrust could corrode his relationships and undermine even the deepest friendships if they truly believed he faked having a stroke. This would eventually, or immediately, lead to anger.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you define "reasonably". Since he didn't choose to get a stroke and even many of the risk factors are outside a person's control (age, genetics, etc). It is hard to say that Person A was at fault in a moral sense.

But people could readily be angry about it, and some of that anger might be directed at him. His co-workers need to pick up the slack. Depending on his position, this might have caused them enormous stress and cost the business money. If you waive your requirement that there be no lasting damages, it might have destroyed a small business in which he was a key player for a time-sensitive major project.

His friends and family just went through a lot of worry and stress in addition to losing the benefit of his work. Events have been missed. Perhaps this persons child was forced to miss a major event like Prom. They might know intellectually it wasn't really his fault but still feel angry or even blame him.

Depending on the society, there might also be substantial medical bills which put a strain on the family. They may well be angry about that even if they could recover from them. Why, he or his family might even be [tempted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_Bad) to start producing industrial quantities of illegal drugs to pay those medical bills if they have the right skills.

Comment: This person could also have lost their reliability, such as a pilot, so they lose their job and their income, which would affect their home life.  "Hey, aren't you that pilot that almost killed +300 people on the jumbo jet?"  "Yes, but the autopilot should have taken over, and it wasn't my fault the co-pilot was in the toilet."  "Yeah, yeah, everyone has excuses..."

Answer (score 0):

### To build your world

1) The mob, people that are permanently angry at him, needs to have a specific type of personality.

2) He needs to be expected to do something.  Most likely, this "something" needs to have a major benefit for the individuals of the mob.

3) There must be rules and regulations that prevent him from doing "something".

4) All possible fixes for (3) are impossible.

This is a generalization of a real life situation.  I don't know if the one person is still angry at the othger due to his medical condition or for other reasons.